# Text Classification Naive Bayes not working as expected

Tags: machine-learning, classification, naive-bayes

I am trying to use Naive Bayes to perform text classification. I have two classes A and B. I am mainly interested in identifying class A.

Description about the dataset:

1. Some of the text contents that belong to class A can also be found in class B.
2. But some of the text contents are only found in class A.
3. The entire dataset is pretty small.

---

**Training Set:**

*Number of Datapoints for class A:* **275**

*Number of Datapoints for class B:* **691**

**Testing Set:**

*Number of Datapoints for class A:* **238**

*Number of Datapoints for class B:* **403**

---

I am using sci-kit learn's multinomialNB to perform the text classification.

***The result that I got after running the Naive Bayes classifier on my test set:***

*Number of datapoints for class A (True Positive): 0*

*Number of datapoints for class B (True Negative): 401*

*Number of datapoints for class A (False Positive): 2*

*Number of datapoints for class B (False Negative): 238*

**EDIT:**

I would like to know how can I improve the classification result of the aforementioned dataset?

Comment: What actualy is your question...?

Comment: @Unhandledexception edited my question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a different classifier like logistic regression. Logistic regression is easier to regularize and that will help you avoid the problem of always predicting the same class.